# Bug in php code that I cant seem to find :-(

Tags: mysql, csv

I have made the following script to upload a csv and import it into my MYSQL DB, this was my working test, it worked just fine. The problem came with the second example, I added all the fields too it to import but now its not doing a lot, its not giving any errors, it literally just prints the following to the page whenever I try to import anything now :

EDIT >>>>>>>

Is there a way I can turn the INSERT IGNORE message below into some kind of usable error message ?, as at the moment its just echoing the insert command instead of actually showing me any kind of error ?.

```
                        Import Successful : name
    - INSERT IGNORE hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead (salutation, leadname, business, address, town, county, postcode, phone, email, gasoiluser,  dervuser, kerouser, annualconsgasoil, annualconsderv, annualconskero, gasoilmargin, dervmargin, keromargin, fueldetails, lubesdetails, otherdetails, sentletterday, sentlettermonth, sentletteryear, sentpostcardday, sentpostcardmonth, sentpostcardyear, sentquoteday, sentquotemonth, sentquoteyear, lastvisitedday, lastvisitedmonth, lastvisitedyear, receivegasoilmailinglist, receivedervmailinglist, receivekeromailinglist, gasoilmailinglist, dervmailinglist, keromailinglist, mailtype, createdby) VALUES ('salutation','name','business name','address','town','county','postcode','phone','email','gasoil user','derv user','kero user','annual consumption gas oil','annual consumption derv','annual consumption kero','gas oil margin','derv margin','kero margin','fuel details','lubes details','other details','sent letter day','sent letter month','sent letter year','sent postcard day','sent postcard month','sent postcard year','sent quote day','sent quote month','sent quote year','last visited day','last visited month','last visited year','mailtype','receive gasoil mailing list frequency','receive derv mailing list frequency','receivekero mailing list frequency','gasoil mailing list','derv mailinglist','kero mailinglist')
```

This was my initial testing code I used to check that the upload and import function was working properly :

```
    <?php
    //database connect info here

    //check for file upload
    if(isset($_FILES['csv_file']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'])){

        //upload directory
        $upload_dir = "./csv";

        //create file name
        $file_path = $upload_dir . $_FILES['csv_file']['name'];

        //move uploaded file to upload dir
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {

            //error moving upload file
            echo "Error moving file upload";

        }

        //open the csv file for reading
        $handle = fopen($file_path, 'r');


        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE) {

            //Access field data in $data array ex.
            $leadname = $data[0];
            $postcode = $data[1];
            $phone = $data[2];
            echo 'Import Successful : ';
            echo $leadname;
            echo '<br/>';

            //Use data to insert into db
            $sql = sprintf("INSERT IGNORE hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead (leadname, postcode, phone) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')",
                        mysql_real_escape_string($leadname),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($postcode),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($phone)
                        );
            mysql_query($sql) or (mysql_query("ROLLBACK") and die(mysql_error() . " - $sql"));
        }


        //delete csv file
        unlink($file_path);
    }
    ?>
```

I then went on and added all the fields.......now for some reason its not importing, and is just printing the message at the top of the page. I know I probably have missed something somewhere but I cant find it for the life of me.

```
    <?php
    //database connect info here

    //check for file upload
    if(isset($_FILES['csv_file']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'])){

        //upload directory
        $upload_dir = "./csv";

        //create file name
        $file_path = $upload_dir . $_FILES['csv_file']['name'];

        //move uploaded file to upload dir
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {

            //error moving upload file
            echo "Error moving file upload";

        }

        //open the csv file for reading
        $handle = fopen($file_path, 'r');


        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE) {

            //Access field data in $data array ex.
                        $salutation = $data[0];
                        $leadname = $data[1];                           
                        $business = $data[2];
                        $address = $data[3];
                        $town = $data[4];
                        $county = $data[5];
                        $postcode = $data[6];
                        $phone = $data[7];                          
                        $email = $data[8];
                        $gasoiluser = $data[9];
                        $dervuser = $data[10];
                        $kerouser = $data[11];
                        $annualconsgasoil = $data[12];
                        $annualconsderv = $data[13];
                        $annualconskero = $data[14];
                        $gasoilmargin = $data[15];
                        $dervmargin = $data[16];
                        $keromargin = $data[17];
                        $fueldetails = $data[18];   
                        $lubesdetails = $data[19];  
                        $otherdetails = $data[20];                          
                        $sentletterday = $data[21];
                        $sentlettermonth = $data[22];
                        $sentletteryear = $data[23];
                        $sentpostcardday = $data[24];
                        $sentpostcardmonth = $data[25];
                        $sentpostcardyear = $data[26];                          
                        $sentquoteday = $data[27];
                        $sentquotemonth = $data[28];
                        $sentquoteyear = $data[29];
                        $lastvisitedday = $data[30];
                        $lastvisitedmonth = $data[31];
                        $lastvisitedyear = $data[32];
                        $receivegasoilmailinglist = $data[33];
                        $receivedervmailinglist = $data[34];
                        $receivekeromailinglist = $data[35];
                        $gasoilmailinglist = $data[36];
                        $dervmailinglist = $data[37];
                        $keromailinglist = $data[38];   
                        $mailtype = $data[39];                      
                        $createdby = $data[40];

            echo 'Import Successful : ';
            echo $leadname;
            echo '<br/>';

            //Use data to insert into db
            $sql = sprintf("INSERT IGNORE hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead (salutation, leadname, business, address, town, county, postcode, phone, email, gasoiluser, dervuser, kerouser, annualconsgasoil, annualconsderv, annualconskero, gasoilmargin, dervmargin, keromargin, fueldetails, lubesdetails, otherdetails, sentletterday, sentlettermonth, sentletteryear, sentpostcardday, sentpostcardmonth, sentpostcardyear, sentquoteday, sentquotemonth, sentquoteyear, lastvisitedday, lastvisitedmonth, lastvisitedyear, receivegasoilmailinglist, receivedervmailinglist, receivekeromailinglist, gasoilmailinglist, dervmailinglist, keromailinglist, mailtype, createdby) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",
                        mysql_real_escape_string($salutation),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($leadname),                            
                        mysql_real_escape_string($business),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($address),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($town),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($county),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($postcode),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($phone),                           
                        mysql_real_escape_string($email),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($gasoiluser),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($dervuser),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($kerouser),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($annualconsgasoil),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($annualconsderv),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($annualconskero),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($gasoilmargin),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($dervmargin),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($keromargin),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($fueldetails), 
                        mysql_real_escape_string($lubesdetails),    
                        mysql_real_escape_string($otherdetails),                            
                        mysql_real_escape_string($sentletterday),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($sentlettermonth),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($sentletteryear),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($sentpostcardday),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($sentpostcardmonth),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($sentpostcardyear),                            
                        mysql_real_escape_string($sentquoteday),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($sentquotemonth),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($sentquoteyear),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($lastvisitedday),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($lastvisitedmonth),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($lastvisitedyear),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($mailtype),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($receivegasoilmailinglist),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($receivedervmailinglist),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($receivekeromailinglist),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($gasoilmailinglist),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($dervmailinglist),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($keromailinglist),                         
                        mysql_real_escape_string($createdby)
                        );
            mysql_query($sql) or (mysql_query("ROLLBACK") and die(mysql_error() . " - $sql"));
        }


        //delete csv file
        unlink($file_path);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  SO is not meant to be a "debug my code" site - if that's what you are looking for, you should probably hire an expert to do it for you, as this can be quite a big task. If you have a *specific* technical question arising of your working on the issue, feel free to edit the question accordingly. What you probably need to do is step-by-step debugging

Comment: Sorry, I just thought if I had made a blatant mistake in my code someone could see if straight away, as I have not been coding that long, so it might be less of a typo and more of me using the wrong syntax somewhere.

Comment: yeah, I understand. But it's *really* tough to spot a mistake in this much code - debugging is probably the way to go. Don't worry, it's normal - we've all been through it many times :)

Comment: Ok, I have edited my question, is there any way I can get mysql to actually give me a usable error, as I have a or die at the end but its not actually doing a lot.

Comment: I spotted something after all, see answer.

Comment: Please note that this approach to file upload is very insecure. It is possible for a user to upload a file to anywhere the web user has access, under any name. This almost certainly means you have a remote code execution hole. Not to mention the cross-site-scripting risks of file uploads (on top of the cross-site-scripting risks you have from missing HTML-escaping). File uploads are hard to get right but the starting point is: never use a user-submitted filename as the basis of a server-side filename, and put user-uploaded files in a safe place outside the web root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work in PHP:

```
mysql_query($sql) or (mysql_query("ROLLBACK") and die(mysql_error() . " - $sql"));
```

two problems:

- you don't use "and" this way; create a control sturcture instead.
- you are running the ROLLBACK command and *then* querying for the SQL error - that probably overrides `mysql_error()`'s value.

Try this for error handling:

```
$error = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$query) 
 { 
   echo mysql_error() . " - $sql";
   mysql_query("ROLLBACK"); 
   die();
 }
```

Comment: Ah thanks !, I am getting errors now, what does this mean ?, Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 -

Comment: does it mean I dont have enough values compared to the amount of columns I am inserting ?

Comment: @user yup, it means that the number of columns you're inserting doesn't match the number of columns that are actually in the table.

Comment: Ok I was missing a '%s' value, the error has gone away, but its still not working, hmm, more wading through the code....

Comment: Its all working now, thanks for the help, I had a combo of wrongly spelt column names and also mismatch of columns to values.